# Display a message in Visual Studio 2019 output window via msbuild target in csproj file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

.NET Core 2.2 Web app, Visual Studio 2019 pro

I added this in my csproj file, but see no message in the output window?

```
  <Target Name="DisplayMessages">
    <Message Text="Project build config = $(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your `Importance` to `High` or adjust your MSBuild settings to turn up the level, but that could create additional noise.

By default Visual Studio does Miminial logging which only `High` will get thru.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/message-task?view=vs-2019